# How to show tasks in Backlog iteration

Tags: tfs

I have some problem with tfs. I created iteration *somename* and than I created some tasks. They are active and in *classification* -> *iteration* field i used *somename*. But I looked at Backlogs and tasks in my newly created iterations (which is *current* iteration) didn't show up. Could you tell me how can i view this tasks on backlog and board?

P.S. I have assigned all the tasks to the teammates, I filled the capacities and filled original estimates to every task. And I would like to see work details and burndown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the tasks have as parrent a Product Backlog Item and does this PBI belong to the same iteration as the tasks do? Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: The backlog only shows Product Backlog Items (aka User Stories).  You need to make a PBI with iteration = "somename". Then make the tasks you have created children of this PBI. Then they PBI and the child tasks will show up in the backlog and the task board.